# Relations with DbQuery

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, relationship, ef-core-2.2

I have this Participant model `DbSet<Participants>`:

```
public class Participant {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int IsCaptain { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }

}
```

And this ParticipantDataView `DbQuery<ParticipantsDataView>`:

```
public class ParticipantDataView {

    public Guid Id { get; set; } // = Participant.Id

    public double? FirstWeight { get; set; }
    public double? LastWeight { get; set; }
    public double? WeightLoss => FirstWeight - LastWeight;

    public Participant Participant { get; set; }

}
```

DbContext:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext {

    public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<ParticipantDataView> ParticipantsDataView { get; set; }

}
```

My query:

```
Participants = await _context.ParticipantsDataView
.Include(p => p.Participant)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Team)
.Where(p => p.Participant.Status == 1 && p.Participant.Team.Status == 1).OrderBy(p => p.WeightLoss)
.AsNoTracking()
.ToListAsync();
```

The error:

```
SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.
This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

Every item in ParticipantDataView has a match in Participants so I don't know why I get this error?

Comment: Have you tried v2.2? Because it seems to work as expected there.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.2 doesn't seem to solve it. Please see my updated question (the UPDATED section).

Comment: That's a totally different story. What I did was with your initial design, added `public DbQuery<ParticipantDataView> ParticipantDataView { get; set; }` to my `DbContext`, mapped it to a view and then used `_context.ParticipantDataView.Include(e => e.Participant)` which worked. Will check the updated scenario when have some time.

Comment: Yes, I know it's different than the original question, but in my search for a solution I ended up with this that I like better. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. It's explicitly stated in the [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) documentation - *Entities cannot contain navigation properties to query types.*. So `public ParticipantDataView ParticipantDataView { get; set; }` inside `Participant` entity won't work.

Comment: I thought it was the other way around. That the query type couldn't be the principal?

Comment: Please see the updated question, thanks!